# Unable to dynamically populate lightning tree grid

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

I am hitting errors trying to dynamically populate a `lightning-tree-grid`. I ran the example from the documentation which worked, but when I tried to dynamically populate the table, I unable to get the grid to populate. The error is `[can't access property "id", e[r] is undefined]`. I will have multiple levels, but I was initially trying to get the first level populated.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:30rem;" tabindex="0">
        <lightning-card  variant="Narrow" icon-name="standard:account">
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
                <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
                    <lightning-tree-grid
                        columns={gridColumns}
                        data={gridData}
                        key-field="id"
                    ></lightning-tree-grid>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import fetchProducts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountActiveProductsController.fetchProducts';

export default class AccountActiveProducts extends LightningElement {
    gridData = [];
    roles = {};

    get gridColumns() {
        return [
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'productName',
                label: 'Product Name',
            },
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'status',
                label: 'Status',
            },
    
        ];
    }

    @wire(fetchProducts)
    getProducts(data) {
        if(data) {
            var finaldata=[];
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                this.roles[data[i].id] = { 
                    productName: data[i].Name,
                    status: 'Green'              
                };
            }
            finaldata.push(this.roles[data[i].id]);
            this.gridData=finaldata;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, we're going to create an object that has each record according to its Id, adding a `_children` array for storing children.

```
let mapping = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(
    row => [
      row.Id,
      { ...row, _children: [], ParentId: row.ParentId || null }
    ]
  )
);
// This key represents top-level nodes (no parent)
mapping[null] = { _children: [] };
```

Second, we add each child to the appropriate parent record:

```
Object.values(mapping).forEach(
  row => {
    mapping[row.ParentId]._children.push(row);
  }
);
```

At this point, your hierarchy is complete. To get the final tree grid data, just get the null key:

```
this.gridData = mapping[null]._children;
```

Make sure that you pay attention to case sensitivity. You may need to change `Id` and `ParentId` appropriately for your data. `_children` is the special key that is used by the tree grid to show child records.